# Error running command (re-run needed): AccountNotFound: solana

Tags: deployment, smartcontracts, nft, metaplex, solana-cli

[img of the cache.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kviFK.png) i am using metaplex to deploy a contract in Solana mainnet --
and I am getting this error when i deploy --
i did upload the art and metadata using NFT-STORAGE everything goes well --

[err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mrD0.png)

Comment: 1) you are not deploying a contract.

Comment: 2) Open the file cache.json is there a candy machine address inside? Is it the one that is shown in the screenshot? Are you sure that you are working in the same environment as where the cache file was created for? (Devnet/mainnet-Beta)

Comment: the cache file was created for mainnet 
and the place for the address is empty !!

Comment: what is the reason of that !
i did the same thing in the devnet and it worked, i did a second try in the main net and the same thing !
Also i didn't put any fund in the account ( balance 0 SOL ) , i didnt want to put nothing till everthing is good !

Comment: well, if you did not fund your account that might have been the reason. Most likely sugar does not expect that someone would not have the funds to pay for the first cheap transaction.

Comment: yes u are Right  ! I didnt Fund it -- I did Fund it and now i the Contract Cost 9.3 SOL ( 5555 NFT in the Collection )  
Metaplex - Sugar !